# turtlebot with stereo camera

Tags: turtlebot, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi, i am new in ros and gazebo. can i use the  turtlebot in simulation (Gazebo) with stereo camera instead of Kinect ? how can apply this?
thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/282985/turtlebot-with-stereo-camera/) by [zahra.kh](https://answers.ros.org/users/32216/zahra.kh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2018-02-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi zahra
in this [link](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=ros_gzplugins) you can find how to use stereo camera in gazebo after that all you need to update  [turtlebot urdf](http://wiki.ros.org/turtlebot_description)

---

Originally posted by [Hamid Didari](https://answers.ros.org/users/6486/hamid-didari/) with karma: 1769 on 2018-02-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [zahra.kh](https://answers.ros.org/users/32216/zahra.kh/) on 2018-02-17**:
thanks hamid